# How to do union between views with parameters?

Tags: sql

Lets assume I have two views with parameters :

how I can do unuion between the views

for example  :

```
CREATE VIEW1 patientGP AS
SELECT GP
FROM patientA
WHERE PFirstName = ['Please input patient name: '];


CREATE VIEW2 patientGP AS
SELECT GP
FROM patientB
WHERE PLastName = ['Please input patient name: '];
```

how to do UNION between VIEW1 and VIEW2 with all the parameters ?

Comment: Just select ... UNION select ...

Comment: I want to do the UNION between the VIEWS  and not the patientA. also how I can pass the parameters in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use parameters in a view one way is to create a package which will set the values of your parameters and have functions that can be called to get those values.

Create two package which contains one function each to get your inputs. Then create your view where the parameters can be referred as `YOURVIEW_PKG1.PARAM1`, `YOURVIEW_PKG2.PARAM2` etc.

Then call the package to set the values for views.

```
exec YOURVIEW_PKG1.SET_VALUES('VAL1');
exec YOURVIEW_PKG2.SET_VALUES('VAL2');
```

Then

```
select * from yourview1 UNION select * from yourview2;
```